# Finding the right Regular Expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Having hard time finding the correct regex in JavaScript.

this is the test string

```
[tr1,1,70,18][jl2]39th St [nl1]Adams Blvd [tr71,1,39,18][jl3]$0.70[nl1]$0.80[tr1,19,110,8][jl3]HOV2+ W/FLEX $0
```

and I'd like to find an expression that matches all of the 3 string below:

```
[tr1,1,70,18][jl2]39th St [nl1]Adams Blvd 

[tr71,1,39,18][jl3]$0.70[nl1]$0.80

[tr1,19,110,8][jl3]HOV2+ W/FLEX $0
```

I managed to get close with this regex which matches the **[tr** portions but need the rest of the text as well.

```
\[tr\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+\]
```

regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/r/eBuUsZ/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's nothing starts with `[tr` other than the beginning of the group, you may try this regex:

```
\[tr(?:(?!\[tr).)*
```

- `\[tr` starting with `[tr`
- `(?:(?!\[tr).)*` matching every character after it unless there's an another `[tr` ahead

```js
const text = '[tr1,1,70,18][jl2]39th St [nl1]Adams Blvd [tr71,1,39,18][jl3]$0.70[nl1]$0.80[tr1,19,110,8][jl3]HOV2+ W/FLEX $0';

const regex = /\[tr(?:(?!\[tr).)*/g;

const result = text.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Or you can try this one for safer choice:

```
\[tr\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+\](?:(?!\[tr\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+\]).)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be matching the first `[tr` part with 1 or more comma separated digits, followed by repeatedly matching parts between square brackets that do not start with `tr`

```
\[tr\d+(?:,\d+)+](?:\[(?!tr)[^][]+][^][]*)+
```

The pattern matches

- `\[tr` Match `[tr`
- `\d+(?:,\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times a comma and 1+ digits
- `]` Match a `]` char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[(?!tr)` Match `[` and assert that it is not directly followed ty `tr`
  - `[^][]+]` Match from `[` till `]`
  - `[^][]*` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C507bk/1)

```js
const s = '[tr1,1,70,18][jl2]39th St [nl1]Adams Blvd [tr71,1,39,18][jl3]$0.70[nl1]$0.80[tr1,19,110,8][jl3]HOV2+ W/FLEX $0';
const regex = /\[tr\d+(?:,\d+)+](?:\[(?!tr)[^\][\n]+][^\][\n]*)+/g;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```